# Best way to set up a modular program in C#

Tags: c#, .net, module

My friend and I are writing an IRC C# bot, and we are looking for a way to include a module system so that users can write custom modules to extend function.

The bot uses Regex to split up all raw data from the server, and then triggers the appropriate event with the data. For example, a typical event handler might look like:

```
OnChannelMessage(object sender, ChannelMessageEventArgs e)
{
}
```

In `ChannelMessageEventArgs` would be the channel name, the nick of the sender, message etc...

I'd like to have a plugin system so that people can build modules and load / unload them at will, when the bot loads, or while its running.

Ideally I'd like to be able to compile the `.cs` files on the fly, and in the plugin.cs file, would be a few things:

1. what event to capture, for example, OnChannelMessage, and the Channeldata in OnChannelEventArgs
2. what to do when this information is given,
3. a help text in (that i can call from inside the main bot.. so say a string, help = "this is the help for this plugin" that can be returned at any time without actually calling the plugin)
4. what the plugin name is etc

Thanks for any ideas on where to start for someone who is relatively new at programming.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've used stuff like this on projects before, but it's been a while.  There are probably frameworks out there that do this kind of stuff for you.

To write your own plug-in architecture, basically you want to define an interface for all the modules to implement, and put this in an assembly shared by both your program and the modules:

```
public interface IModule
{
     //functions/properties/events of a module
}
```

Then your implementors will code their modules to this assembly, preferably with a default constructor.

```
public class SomeModule : IModule {} ///stuff
```

In your program (supposing your modules will be compiled into their own assemblies) you load a reference an assembly containing a module, find the types that implement the module interface, and instantiate them:

```
var moduleAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("assembly file");
var moduleTypes = moduleAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => 
   t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IModule)));

var modules = moduleTypes.Select( type =>
            {   
               return  (IModule) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            });
```

If you want to compile the code on the fly: you create a compiler object, tell it what assemblies to reference (System and the one that contains IModule, plus any other references needed), tell it to compile the source file into an assembly.  From that, you get the exported types, filter keeping those which implement the IModule, and instantiate them.

```
//I made up an IModule in namespace IMod, with string property S
string dynamicCS = @"using System; namespace DYN 
             { public class Mod : IMod.IModule { public string S 
                 { get { return \"Im a module\"; } } } }";

var compiler = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider().CreateCompiler();
var options = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters(
       new string[]{"System.dll", "IMod.dll"});

var dynamicAssembly= compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, dynamicCS);
//you need to check it for errors here

var dynamicModuleTypes = dynamicAssembly.CompiledAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMod.IModule)));
var dynamicModules = dynModType.Select(t => (IMod.IModule)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
```

Look up tutorials on plug-in architectures and loading dynamic assmeblies to get a better feel for doing this kind of stuff.  This is just the start. Once you get the basics down, you can start doing some really cool things.

As for handling the metadata (module X is named YYY and should handle events A,B and C):
Try to work this into your type system.  You could make up different interfaces for the different functions/events, or you could put all the functions on one interface, and put attributes (you'd declare these in the shared assembly) on the module classes, using the attributes to declare which events the module should subscribe to.  Basically you want to make it as simple as possible for people to write modules for your system.

```
 enum ModuleTypes { ChannelMessage, AnotherEvent, .... }

 [Shared.Handles(ModuleTypes.ChannelMessage)]
 [Shared.Handles(ModuleTypes.AnotherEvent)]
 class SomeModule : IModule { ... }
```

or

```
 //this is a finer-grained way of doing it
 class ChannelMessageLogger : IChannelMessage {}
 class PrivateMessageAutoReply : IPrivateMessage {}
```

have fun!

Comment: I would highly recommend using existing plugin frameworks like MEF or System.AddIns; they'll save you a lot of plumbing headaches.

Comment: Me too, but the OP asked for a non-framework solution. Plus the basics are nice to know

Comment: If I could upvote this again a few times, I would. I learned alot from the code you provided 3 years ago.

Comment: "If you want to compile the code on the fly". Why would I want that? I couldn't think of a reason. I mean, I should have the plugin dlls ready beforehand. Why would I create these dlls in the program instead of visual studio, msbuild or a build server?

Comment: @sotn You're right, you almost never want this! It's almost always a terrible idea.
A few things that I've seen effectively use dynamic compilation: cshtml files in asp.net mvc; Linqpad; NDepend code queries. 
Another real use case I know of where you *could* use this (but shouldn't): imagine you want to let users generate arbitrary reports on production website. There are many ways to do this, but one (dangerous) way is to let users write linq queries in an html form and then have the server compile and execute it against a data set.

Comment: @sotn why would you ever want any non-pre-compiled / interpreted scripting language? The original goal of this (almost a decade ago) was to allow small scripts (written in C#, for simplicity) to be added, removed, and edited without needing to take the underlying system offline incurring downtime. While these scripts could've been pre-compiled, the nature of them was to be tweaked constantly and all it would've done is added overhead. I don't think it's the job of people on SOF to ask why someone else could want something.

Comment: @caesay It is my "job" to learn whatever I want and stackoverflow is one of the best ways for me. I wanted to learn what use cases does compiling the code on the fly are and got an answer too so why bother..

Comment: I think it’s very reasonable to ask why someone wants or would want something It’s a good way to learn. Even if the answer is “It’s not a real problem, I was just curious”. We need to be careful though because tone doesn’t come across well on the internet. So asking “why do you want this?” could be interpreted as an attack even though that wasn’t the intent. Asking “just wondering, what did you have in mind for this?” would probably be received better and open up a better discussion.

Answer (score 18):

The [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://mef.codeplex.com) provides exactly what you are looking for except they call it a Plugin architecture.  You could provide a common interface which you users could build on and then MEF could scan a directory for dlls and load any Exports dynamically.

For example your plugin authors could create something like

```
[Export(typeof(IModule))]
public class MyModule : IModule
{
   void HandleMessage(ChannelEventArgs e) {}
}
```

Then your code could look something like this:

```
void OnChannelMessage(ChannelEventArgs e)
{
  foreach(IModule module in Modules)
  {
     module.HandleMessage(e);
  }
}

[Import]
public IEnumerable<IModule> Modules { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this without using any type of external Frameworks?

Comment: This is open source, so you can look, but with the `FileSystemWatcher`, `Assembly.Load`, and some reflection you should be able to model something similar fairly easily.

Comment: You could write the framework code yourself... Why re-invent the wheel though??

Comment: The Import side would be alot more difficult then the export side.  You may want to avoid the setter injection piece and just use a helper function to get the imports instead.

Comment: @Paolo agreed, especially since this is being shipped with .NET4

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look a microsoft's Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) - It proposes to do some of what you want, and provides a lot of other features:

[Google results for 'managed extensibility framework'](http://www.google.co.il/search?rlz=1C1CHMB_iwIL354IL355&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=managed+extensibility+framework)

Comment: +1 it also might be interesting to note that it will be part of .NET 4.0

Answer (score 3):

There is another option in the hearth of .NET 3.5 called Managed AddIn Framework (MAF). Check the following links out.

Sample and Tools: http://clraddins.codeplex.com/

MAF Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/clraddins/

A good article: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/08/13/Build-AddIns-with-System-AddIn.aspx

Answer (score 2):

MEF - Managed Extensibility Framework is the buzzword right now - I think that would be the best fit.

If that doesnt do the trick you could also look up on [Prism](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF), they have another approach to implement modules.